# how can i fix terminal shell code in visual code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, path

I had tried git with vs code but I got an error ***The terminal shell path "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" does not exist***.

Please help me to fix this issue.

My settings.json file is:

"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"

Thanks in advance

Comment: add double backslashes instead of single backslashes!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. You need to go to settings.json file edit it to
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

You can also follow below link :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Below is the screenshot of the same

[image]